# Unable to run shell script in Terraform

Tags: bash, azure, shell, terraform

I am trying to run a shell script with the local-exec command in Terraform. When I run this, it keeps coming up with the error `"Can't open appsettings.sh"`. This script runs fine when run manually. Any ideas what I am missing?

```
resource "null_resource" "sp" {

  triggers = {
    shell_hash = "${sha256(file("${path.module}/appsettings.sh"))}"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "appsettings.sh ${azuread_application.rbac-server-principal.application_id} ${azuread_application.rbac-client-principal.application_id}"
      interpreter = ["sh"]
      working_dir = "${path.module}"
  }
}
```

error message:

```
Error: Error running command 'appsettings.sh 59942507-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx 4c64-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx': exit status 127. Output: sh: 0: Can't open appsettings.sh 59942507-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx 4c64-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx'
```

Comment: It's not permission issue??

Comment: I don't think so, this is just running on my local desktop machine, all files are local

Comment: Today at work I happened to have a similar case that I used ide and terminal and got different results and there really was a problem of different privileges, I searched for this justification online with your code status without success, but the only result I got is that your file may need to be converted from Linux to Linux .. `https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/5821`

Comment: It looks like it is the command, if I run the same sh command at the prompt it gets this error. If I adjust the quotes I can get it to run locally, but no luck in Terraform as yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is, terraform run the command as

```
["/bin/sh" "-c" "appsettings.sh arg1 arg2"]
```

So the command interpreter take appsettings.sh as the command name which is very similar to running as below

```
$appsettings.sh arg1 arg2
```

which cannot be done as there is no command like this. So to run that shell script you either has to provide the absolute path of the shell script or relative as shown below

```
$ ./appsettings.h
$ /home/user/appsettings.sh # Example
```

To achieve this rearrange your command attr as below

```
command = "./appsettings.sh ${azuread_application.rbac-server-principal.application_id} ${azuread_application.rbac-client-principal.application_id}"

 OR

command = "${path.module}/appsettings.sh ${azuread_application.rbac-server-principal.application_id} ${azuread_application.rbac-client-principal.application_id}"
```

i.e. add **./appsettings**

Answer (score 1):

The error message is stating that it "Can't open" the script file.
The reason might be:

1. The script file is not present (may be it is not yet created on machine)
2. Permission issue

If you are running command through a program (e.g terraform or script) you need to specify the shell and or proper path.
Example:

```
/bin/sh /path/to/script/myscript.sh
or
/bin/bash /path/to/script/myscript.sh
```

The difference between `local-exec` and `remote-exec` is that `local-exec` will run on the machine that is executing the terraform commands while `remote-exec` will run the commands on the created resource using a connection.

Refrances:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html

https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/remote-exec.html

Answer (score 1):

OK I get it now.

## TLDR version

Remove interpreter (`interpreter = ["sh"]`) at all or add `-c` as another parameter, like this: `interpreter = ["sh", "-c"]` or even better `interpreter = ["/bin/sh", "-c"]`. Additionally you need to provide path to script so add `./` or `${path.module}/`.

> NOTE: also as far as I see script needs to be executable (`chmod +x appsettings.sh`).

## Full version

The problem is with default interpretation of `local-exec`. If you do not set  interpreter then the default one is `/bin/sh -c` (Linux) and if you add command/script with parameters/arguments it looks like this

```
["/bin/sh", "-c", "./appsettings.sh a b"]
```

but what you were trying to do is to run something like this

```
["/bin/sh", "./appsettings.sh a b"]
```

If we test both this approaches in terminal then we will see:

```
$ /bin/sh -c "./appsettings.sh a b"
Params: a b
$ /bin/sh "./appsettings.sh a b"
/bin/sh: 0: Can't open ./appsettings.sh a b
```

In `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash` shells `-c` parameters is responsible for:

> *Read commands from the command_string operand instead of from the standard input.*

> *NOTE: if you want to read more check this out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/831847/what-is-the-sh-c-command*

Final corrected script should looks like this:

```
resource "null_resource" "sp" {

  triggers = {
    shell_hash = "${sha256(file("${path.module}/appsettings.sh"))}"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "./appsettings.sh ${azuread_application.rbac-server-principal.application_id} ${azuread_application.rbac-client-principal.application_id}"
  }
}
```

If you would like to use `bash` instead of `sh` then it should be like this:

````
resource "null_resource" "sp" {

  triggers = {
    shell_hash = "${sha256(file("${path.module}/appsettings.sh"))}"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "./appsettings.sh ${azuread_application.rbac-server-principal.application_id} ${azuread_application.rbac-client-principal.application_id}"
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
  }
}```
````